# UICollectionViewCell not shown

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm building an custom menu in a ViewController, which contains two container view controllers.

Top view is a UICollectionViewController (Flow Layout / Horizontal Scroll Direction)

Bottom view is a UIPageViewController

Everthing works fine. However, when I **embedded in a navigation controller**, the collectionviewCell dosen't show up as expected, any ideas?

Also, I found that when embedded with navigation controller, the following functions are not called.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {}
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { }
```

**Without embedded Navigation Controller**

[image]
[image]

**With embedded Navigation Controller**

[image]
[image]

Comment: have u set the datasource/delegate in the storyboard file?

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans, yep. Everything works before embedded with navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you're child view controller containing the collection view, add the code in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` methods as shown below. It should fix your problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length,
                                                        0.0,
                                                        self.bottomLayoutGuide.length,
                                                        0.0)
}
```

Reason being, by default a `UIViewController` instance responds being inside a Navigation controller by updating `contentInset` of `UIScrollView` subclass (In you're case UICollectionView). So here you are just saying do not automatically update the insets.